# Selecting a DataTemplate based on DataContext property in Avalonia

Tags: c#, datatemplate, datatemplateselector, avaloniaui

I'm implementing a UserControl which should display a list of settings:

```
public class SettingPropertyItem {
    string Name { get; }
    Type ValueType { get; }
    object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Based on each type in `ValueType` a different DataTemplate should be used.
To facilitate this the UserControl has the following Control with a `SettingPropertyItem` as its DataContext:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AVDump3Gui.Controls.Settings.SettingsView">
    ...
    <ItemsControl Items="{Binding Properties}" Margin="16,0,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            ...
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

Then the view where the Usercontrol is used, I've added a DataTemplate into its DataTemplates:

```
<sv:SettingsView.DataTemplates>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SettingPropertyItem}">
    ...
  </DataTemplate>
</sv:SettingsView.DataTemplates>
```

So far so good, everything works as expected. But now I'm a bit stumped as I don't know how to apply different DataTemplates based on a Property within the DataContext.
With WPF a DataTemplateSelector or Triggers seem to be the way to go (ignoring additional Frameworks), but they don't seem to exist in Avalonia. I've also tried styles but the selector doesn't seem to be able to access DataContext properties.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Avalonia `DataTemplateSelector` isn't needed because you can just implement `IDataTemplate` yourself and select the template there.

i. e.

```cs
public class MyTemplateSelector : IDataTemplate
{
    public bool SupportsRecycling => false;
    [Content]
    public Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate> Templates {get;} = new Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate>();

    public IControl Build(object data)
    {
        return Templates[((MyModel) data).Value].Build(data);
    }

    public bool Match(object data)
    {
        return data is MyModel;
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
  <ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
      <scg:List x:TypeArguments="local:MyModel">
        <local:MyModel Value="MyKey"/>
        <local:MyModel Value="MyKey2"/>
      </scg:List>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
    <ItemsControl.DataTemplates>
      <local:MyTemplateSelector>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyKey">
          <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyKey2">
          <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        
      </local:MyTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl.DataTemplates>
  </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @kekekeks If all the templates in the `Content` are large, I'd like them in a dedicate Resource Dictionary in several files (maybe one per `DataTemplate`).  How can we reference these in your XAML above instead of inline definition?