# Include Templates from external files instead of inline

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

Since there are no template selector in avalonia XAML, I implemented the `IDataTemplate` as per [the example](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Samples/blob/main/src/Avalonia.Samples/DataTemplates/IDataTemplateSample/README.adoc) and/or [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207058/selecting-a-datatemplate-based-on-datacontext-property-in-avalonia). It works fine.

My templates are pretty large and I want to have them in a separate resource file instead of inline. Using a `ResourceDictionary` did not work: the content type defined in the `IDataTemplate` implementation does not match.

```
public class ShapesTemplateSelector : IDataTemplate
{
    [Content]
    public Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate> AvailableTemplates { get; } = new Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate>();
...
}
```

I tried changing the `[Content]` property type to `public ResourceDictionary` but it resulted in a compilation error:

```
'Unable to find suitable setter or adder...'
```

How to implement `IDataTemplate` while populating its `[Content]` in the XAML with external Files/Templates instead of inline?