Avalonia - Changing DataTemplate based on collection values throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
I'm learning Avalonia and am trying to have an ItemsControl switch between two different DataTemplates based on a property in an ObservableCollection of custom objects.
I have an ObservableCollection<Parameter> called "Parameters" with "Parameter" defined as follows:
public class Parameter
{
  public Parameter(string value = "") {
    if (value.ToLower() == "switch") {
      IsBool = true;
    }
  }
  
  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get { return _name; }
    set {
      _name = value;
    }
  }

  public bool IsBool { get; set; } = false;
}

This is my XAML code where the ItemsControl is defined:
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <Binding Path="IsBool">
      <resources:ParameterTemplateSelector>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="true">
          <Grid Margin="20 10 ">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="600" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{ReflectionBinding Path=Name}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"                   
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <ToggleSwitch Grid.Column="2"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="false">
          <Grid Margin="20 10 ">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="600" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="{ReflectionBinding Path=Name}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
            <AutoCompleteBox Name="AutoCompleteBox" Grid.Column="2"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

      </resources:ParameterTemplateSelector>
    </Binding>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

And here's "ParameterTemplateConverter" (though the code gives the same error without it):
public class ParameterTemplateSelector : IDataTemplate
{
  [Content]
  public Dictionary<bool, IDataTemplate> AvailableTemplates { get; } = new Dictionary<bool, IDataTemplate>();

  public Control Build(object? param)
  {
    var key = param?.Equals(true);

    if (key == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param));
    }
    
    return AvailableTemplates[key.Value].Build(param);
  }

  public bool Match(object? data)
  {
    var key = data?.Equals(true);

    return data is bool
           && key != null
           && AvailableTemplates.ContainsKey(key.Value);
  }
}

Ideally this would create a Grid with a ToggleSwitch for every "IsBool" with a value of true, and one with an AutoCompleteBox for the rest, but attempting to run the code gives me this error, presumably on the "IsBool" bound property:

Error AVLN:0004 Avalonia: Internal compiler error while transforming node XamlX.Ast.XamlAstObjectNode:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

I feel like this is because the collection is empty at runtime, but I don't get this error if I use any of the "Parameter" properties elsewhere, and since I can't populate the collection before runtime I'm not quite sure how to approach solving this.

How is this supposed to work at all? There is no per-item binding of the ItemTemplate property. The current DataContext is not a Parameter object, but the DataContext of the ItemsControl, so there is no DataType property. Besides that, the Convert method should return a value that can be assigned to the ItemTemplate property, i.e. a DataTemplate, not a string.

This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63207058/1136211. See also this: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/get-started/wpf/datatemplates

@Clemens Thanks, it seems I was completely misinterpreting how x:Key works... I went through the pages you linked to, and I think I have a better understanding of it.
I've edited my code to reflect that, but I am still getting the OutOfRangeException. This code did work when I tested it with a basic List populated at creation (the template converter was also using string at that point), but it doesn't seem to work even if I provide "Parameters" with sample values when it's created.

There are mainly two things wrong in your code.
First, the <resources:ParameterTemplateSelector> should not be declared inside a Binding. The XAML should look like this:
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <resources:ParameterTemplateSelector>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="true">
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="false">
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </resources:ParameterTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

Second, the code of the ParameterTemplateSelector should look like shown below. I used #nullable disable for brevity.
Please note that the object that is passed to the Build method is the same as that passed to the Match method. The method parameter should hence also be data, because param is confusing here. The name was just like that because the Build method is declared in a base interface with additional purposes.
#nullable disable

public class ParameterTemplateSelector : IDataTemplate
{
    [Content]
    public Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate> AvailableTemplates { get; }
        = new Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate>();

    public Control Build(object data)
    {
        // cast data to Parameter and access the property value
        var parameter = (Parameter)data;
        var key = parameter.IsBool.ToString().ToLower();

        return AvailableTemplates[key].Build(parameter);
    }

    public bool Match(object data)
    {
        // test if data is an instance of Parameter
        return data is Parameter;
    }
}


As a general note, it seems pointless to introduce the IsBool property in the first place. Better keep a string property that could directly be used as a dictionary key.
Maybe declare the Parameter class like this:
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
}

and use the Kind property as key:
public Control Build(object data)
{
    var parameter = (Parameter)data;

    return AvailableTemplates[parameter.Kind].Build(parameter);
}

with
<resources:ParameterTemplateSelector>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="switch">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="acbox">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</resources:ParameterTemplateSelector>


Thank you! Not sure why I was going for a sub-binding instead of just casting to Parameter.
